# When logout from Spring Security [Boot] and then again if I try to login it's logging in without password. How Can I prevent this

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring security in my application and configuration is mentioned below.

When User is logged out from system and click in again login then I want to display login page.

```java
@Component
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public static class LoginConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        RequestMatcher csrfRequestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {

            // Enabled CSFR protection on the following urls
            private AntPathRequestMatcher[] requestMatchers = { new AntPathRequestMatcher("/dashboard/logout") };

            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                // If the request match one url the CSFR protection will be
                // enabled
                for (AntPathRequestMatcher rm : requestMatchers) {
                    if (rm.matches(request)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            } // method matches

        };

        http.csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher).csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and().antMatcher("/dashboard/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .hasAnyRole("AUTHENTICATED_USER", "ANONYMOUS").and().sessionManagement().sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession().and()
                // .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                // .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)

        .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/dashboard/logout").deleteCookies(new String[]{"XSRF-TOKEN","JSESSIONID","remember-me"})
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().rememberMe().and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The case you mentioned mostly happens if you use a cookie for authentication as a token and the deleteCookie method is not deleting your authentication cookies correctly.

The best way to identify this is follow :

1.Clear all cookies and login and then observe the cookie name and value and path in inspect element of web browser.

2.Logout and then observe the inspect element request and response with cookies.

3.Observe the path of the cookie carefully.

It is important to observe the path of the cookie is because of the path of the cookie at its creation time is different than its deletion time,it will not get deleted.It has to be exactly the same.

When you call .deleteCookies(...),then internally it calls the CookieClearingLogoutHandler(spring boot security internal class) mentioned as below :

```
public final class CookieClearingLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    private final List<String> cookiesToClear;

    public CookieClearingLogoutHandler(String... cookiesToClear) {
        Assert.notNull(cookiesToClear, "List of cookies cannot be null");
        this.cookiesToClear = Arrays.asList(cookiesToClear);
    }

    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        for (String cookieName : cookiesToClear) {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
            String cookiePath = request.getContextPath();
            if(!StringUtils.hasLength(cookiePath)) {
                cookiePath = "/";
            }
            cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe the cookie setPath, you would need to set the cookie path for the cookie you are using for authentication in the same way mentioned in above code.

Hope this helps.